# Multi Language website - is it possible only by saving it multi language file or db

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, multilingual

I  have worked on multilingual websites. it was by keeping all the words in separate files , or arrays or db table and specifying it with some key for language . "EN", "FR" etc.

Is there any better and simple way now a days like Google translate.

Just one click translate the website or localize the website.

Is there any plugin or jquery/js script that can be installed to accheiev this

Comment: I don't think you're going to want to leave it up to a transator to communicate to your customer, since it may not say what you're really wanting to say. Even if you had a human fast enough to translate all the web pages on-the-fly, you would want to have some control over the way they're translating it, wouldn't you? That's the reason for maintaining a phrase database.

Comment: so 2 buddies are saying , keep it in db/file will be good for me and my customers. so you dont want me to be lazy :-)

Comment: On the contrary, laziness (along with impatience and hubris) is a very important trait for any programmer. Your hubris, however, will not allow the variability built into on-the-fly translation. :) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris

Answer (score 1):

Translation services aren't a replacement for localization. If you use Google Translate on a web page, you'll find that the translated text is not very readable to a native speaker. The more difference between the languages, the more awkward the translated text will be. Go to a Chinese or Japanese site and translate with Google... heheh.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you are using a CMS - if you are using Wordpress, try http://wpml.org/ - I use it, it's very good. It creates and manages the language database for you, you just provide it with translations of all your items.